# Store image taken from external camera and store it in DB - Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, base64

I'm creating an application using ionic 3. The app is supposed to do the following: take an image from external camera (it will return it as file URL), store it in local DB using sqllite as base64.

This is my attempt

```
takeImage(){
const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

this.takePicture().subscribe(data => {
    this.wait(7000);
            this.listFiles().subscribe(data => {     
      const url = data['results'].entries[0].fileUrl;
      fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + data['results'].entries[0].name).then((entry) => {
        this.room.img = entry.toURL();
        this.base64.encodeFile( entry.toURL()).then((base64File: string) => {
        this.room.img = base64File;},
        (err) => {
                  console.log(err);
                });
}, (error) => {});
},
   err => {console.log(err);});
   },
   err => {console.log(err);});
}
```

I have tried to display the `base64File` but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

To display a base64 image you need to import DomSanitizer in component and create the instance variable in the constructor below is the code

```
constructor(public _DomSanitizer: DomSanitizer)

<img class="one-image" *ngFor="let image of item; let i= index"    style="height:120px;" [src]="_DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(image.imgUrl)" #images (click)="imageOption(i,images,image.data,image.ext)"/>
```

Comment: I don't think the problem lies in displaying the image. I have tried images from the gallery and shows correctly. Could it the conversion to base64 file is not correct?I'm not sure.

Comment: are you getting proper image url in entry.toUrl() and did you check image is downloded in local files ? . One more question why you are passing two values in this.room.img is image got displayed from entry.toUrl() ?